# Rails Find all objects with same children

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

Using

- Rails 3.2.8
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Postgresql
- Ubuntu 12.10.

Feel like I've completely forgotten how to construct a rails search after being away from rails for a few months.

`Orders has_many Items`.

Items have string `status`: `in_progress`, `canceled`, `completed`.
They also have a boolean of `acquired`.

So, I want to find all 'ready to complete' `orders`, which is to say, orders with all items that have at least one item that has (status `in_progress` and `acquired`), and any that are not in_progress are status `canceled` or status `completed`.

But I don't know how to construct a query that will only return Orders that have items that are *all* meeting those conditions. I have an Order with 3 Items, all are in_progress, one is acquired.

```
orders = Order.includes(:items).where(items: { status: "in_progress", acquired: true })
```

This will return the `Order`, eager loading the 1 `Item` that is `acquired`. But I need a query that will not return any orders, since not all items meet the criteria. But I am not sure where to start, and trying to search for this problem has been really difficult.

I need to check that at least one item is (`in_progress` and `acquired`) any any that are not are `canceled` or `completed`, and that ALL items are this way.

Any push in the right direction would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Rails ActiveModel does not support `OR` queries well yet, so try to use [arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) to build complicated query.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Postgresql syntax, but in Mysql if you want to select orders where all items is "in progress" you should do smth like this:

```
SELECT orders.* FROM orders LEFT JOIN items ON items.order_id = orders.id AND items.status!='in progress' WHERE  items.id IS NULL;
```

OR

```
SELECT orders.* FROM orders INNER JOIN items ON items.order_id = orders.id GROUP BY items.order_id HAVING COUNT(items.id)=SUM(CASE WHEN items.status='in progress' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```

I guess in ActiveRecord:

```
Order.joins("items ON items.order_id = orders.id AND items.status!='in progress'").where("items.id IS NULL")
```

Comment: I can't get these to work, and I think it looks like they basically just find any orders with all items !in_progress. But, I need to find all that are either in progress and acquired, or not in progress, not paused - there are a couple of other statuses it can't be. So it pretty much is that they must be certain status, or in prog and acquired, and all items are that. It seems like these queries just look for orders with items not in progress. But, my sql is pretty bad, admittedly. Will probably need a groupby having, but not sure these are it. [cont]

Comment: So I figured a good start is to just find all orders where items are in progress and in possession, and then work out how to also exclude not in progress items if they were certain status'. But, I think I'm just not able to figure this out. Might be time to finally just spend some serious time learning SQL.

Comment: Also just realized I didn't write exactly what I meant I think (yesterday was tiring): Items should have at least 1 in progress and acquired, and the rest can be either canceled or completed. I figured I would start with finding orders with all items in_progress and acquired. Part of the confusion might be that I said I wanted to find _completed_ orders, when I really meant _nearly completed_, where they are basically waiting for one more thing to complete (are in prog and acquired).